# Parsing JSONArray in Android

Tags: android, json

I am new to json parsing and am caught up big time. I have to parse the following:-

```
[
  {
    "firstname": abc,
    "lastname": xyp,
    "designation" : executive,
    "user": {
      "username": "xypabc",
      "userid": 4003,
      },
  },

  {
    "firstname": pqr,
    "lastname": vbn,
    "designation" : security,
    "user": {
      "username": "vbnpqr",
      "userid": 11231,
      },
  },    


  {
    "firstname": ghk,
    "lastname": lkj,
    "designation" : manager,
    "user": {
      "username": "lkjghk",
      "userid": 774,
      },
  }
]
```

I need to fetch the "login" and "userid" from above. Below is the code which I wrote :-

```
try {
    JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(response);
    for(int i=0 ; i<jsonObj.length(); i++)
    {                                       
        JSONObject json_Data = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);
        String userName = json_Data.getString("username");
        String userId = json_Data.getString("userid");
        Log.d("Factors","UserName :- "+userName+" ID :- "+userId);
    }
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d("Failure","Dude I have failed");
    }.
```

The problem is that my code ends up with exception.
Please help !!!

Comment: your forgot parsing `"user": {` under which you ahve username and id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`username` and `userid`  is within the `user` JSONObject parse the user JSONObject and then get the string of the username and userid.

DO like this to get the `username` and `userid`

```
for(int i=0 ; i<jsonObj.length(); i++)
    {                                       
        JSONObject json_Data = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);
        String userName = json_Data.getJSONObject("user").getString("username");
        String userId = json_Data.getJSONObject("user").getString("userid");
        Log.d("Factors","UserName :- "+userName+" ID :- "+userId);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Nambi Narayanan .. works wonderfully !!! ... but I regret I cant "vote-up" ur answer as i dont have enough reputation :( . Neways thanks a ton

Comment: Consider looking into the Gson parser as well, it is quite amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing: "user"

```
   try {
        JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(response);
        for(int i=0 ; i<jsonObj.length(); i++)
        {                                       
            JSONObject json_Data = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject user = json_Data.getJSONObject("user");
            String userName = user.getString("username");
            String userId = user.getString("userid");
            Log.d("Factors","UserName :- "+userName+" ID :- "+userId);
        }
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("Failure","Dude I have failed");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jresult = new JSONArray(response);

jresult = json.getJSONArray("user");
for (int i = 0; i < jresult .length(); i++) 
{
JSONObject obj  = jresult .getJSONObject(i);
String username=obj.getString("username");
int userid=obj.getInt("userid");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(result != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    JSONObject jobj = result.getJSONObject("result");

                    String status = jobj.getString("status");

                    if(status.equals("true"))
                    {
                        JSONArray array = jobj.getJSONArray("user");

                        for(int x = 0; x < array.length(); x++)
                        {
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            map.put("username", array.getJSONObject(x).getString("username"));

                            map.put("userid", array.getJSONObject(x).getString("userid"));



                            list.add(map);
                        }

                        CalendarAdapter adapter = new CalendarAdapter(Calendar.this, list);

                        list_of_calendar.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code : :)

```
  JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(response);
                for(int i=0 ; i<jsonObj.length(); i++)
                {                                       
                    JSONObject json_Data = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);
                    String firstname = json_Data.getString("firstname");
                    String lastname = json_Data.getString("lastname");
                    String designation = json_Data.getString("designation");

                    JSONArray jsons1 = json_Data.getJSONArray("user");
                    for (int j = 0; j < jsons1.length(); j++) {

                        JSONObject jsonss = jsons1.getJSONObject(j);
                         String username = jsonss.getString("username");
                            String userid = jsonss.getString("userid");
                    }

                }
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d("Failure","Dude I have failed");
                }
```